# Big-O-Notation, calcuation rule

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory, proof

I've got a question about the Big-O-Notation.
We have zu proof or show, that the following statemates, are not correct. And i've got no clue how to show it.

a) Given a Polynom p with the degree of k >= 1: log(p(n)) ∈ Θ(log(n))

b)  f, g ∈ Θ(h) ⇒ |f − g| ∈ Θ(h), where |f − g| : n → |f(n) − g(n)|

Can anyone of you tell me what is correct an what not an maybe explaine me how can show this?

Comment: i know this might be a very specific question and i will tell you what i'm up to: i guess a) is wrong, can i proove it with an example that will not work?
and can anyone tell me how can i get the second one? i don't unterstand what the statement means

Comment: the question is answered, thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

> a) Given a Polynom p with the degree of k >= 1: log(p(n)) ∈ Θ(log(n))

Let p(n) = a[0] + a[1]n + a[2]n^2 + ... + a[k]n^k with k >= 1. To show Theta we must show O and Omega, or O both ways. To show O, we show that there exists a c such that for n > n0, log(p(n)) <= c log(n). First, we note that a <= b iff e^a <= e^b (since e^x is monotonically increasing). Therefore, log(p(n)) <= c log(n) iff p(n) <= n^c. We may factor from every term of p(n) the highest-order term n^k and the absolute value of the coefficient with largest magnitude (call this a') to get: p(n) = (n^k)(a')(b[0]/n^k + b[1]/n^(k-1) + ... + b[n]). Note that all b[n] < 1 and thus we have p(n) < (n^k)(a')n. But p(n) < (n^k)(a')n = n^(k+1)(a') <= n^c. Let c = k + 1 + z. Then we need n^(k+1)(a') <= n^(k+1)(n^z) which is true if a' <= n^z. As long as n > 1, there exists a z such that n^z > a' for any fixed a': choose z > log_n a'.

Showing the O the other way around is left as an exercise. Hint: n^k <= p(n).

Comment: than you for your answer! i will try the omega, that is left to show theta when i have time after work totay! but i have to thank you for now!

Comment: @ElisabethPachl To show Theta, you can show (a) O and Omega one way, or (b) O both ways, or (c) Omega both ways. f = Theta(g) iff (a) f = O(g) and f = Omega(g); or (b) f = O(g) and g = O(f); or (c) f = Omega(g) and g = Omega(f). These properties are true since f = O(g) iff g = Omega(f).

Comment: i think i understand generally what you are doing in your proof, but what is the a* means`

Comment: @ElisabethPachl I have cleared up the later part of the argument since I noticed it was sloppy. I removed `a*` and use `a'` now. `a'` is equal to the absolute value of the coefficient with the largest absolute value. So if p(n) = 3 - 7n^2 + 2n^100, a' = 7.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

Let's define

```
k := deg(p)
A := max(|ck|, ..., |c0|)
```

where the `ci` are the coefficients of `p`. Then

```
|p(n)| <= |ck|n^k + ... + |c1|n + |c0|
       <= A n^k + ... + A n + A
       <= A n^k + ... + A n^k + A n^k
       <= (k+1)A n^k
```

then

```
log(|p(n)|) <= log((k+1)A) + k log(n)
            <= (log((k+1)A) + k) log(n)
```

because `log` is an increasing function and `1 <= log(n)` for `n >> 1`. In other words

```
log(|p(n)|) ∈ (log(n))
```

(Note that I've used `|p(n)|` rather than `p(n)` to include the case where `p(n) < 0`.)

**Step 2**

For `i = 0, 1, ..., k-1` let's define

```
di := |ci|/|ck|
```

and

```
s := d_{k-1} + ... + d0
```

their sum.

Now take an integer `n0` such that `n0 >= 2s`. For any `n >= n0` we have

```
n >= 2s
```

or

```
n/2 >= d_{k-1} + ... + d0
    >= d_{k-1} + ... + d0/n^{k-1}
```

multiplying by `n^{k-1}`

```
(n^k)/2 >= d_{k-1} n^{k-1} + ... + d0
```

thus, for `n >= n0` we get

```
|p(n)| = |ck n^k + c_{k-1} n^{k-1} + ... + c0|
       = |ck||n^k + c_{k-1}/ck n^{k-1} + ... + c0/ck|
       >= |ck|(n^k - |c_{k-1}/ck n^{k-1} + ... + c0/ck|)
       >= |ck|(n^k - |d_{k-1} n^{k-1} + ... + d0|)
       >= |ck|(n^k - (n^k)/2)
       = |ck|/2 n^k
```

Taking `log`

```
 log(|p(n)|) >= log(|ck|/2) + k log(n) ∈ (log(n))
```

**First Conclusion**

From steps 1 and 2 above:

```
 log(|p(n)|) ∈ (log(n))
```

**Step 3**

Let `f, g ∈ Θ(h)` then

```
|f(n) − g(n)| <= |f(n)| + |g(n)|
              <= A h(n) + B h(n)
              <= (A+B)h(n) ∈ (h)
```

**However**

It is not generally true that `|f(n) − g(n)| ∈ Θ(h)`. Here is an example:

```
 f(n) = n^k + n^{k-1}
 g(n) = n^k
```

Both functions belong in `Θ(n^k)` while

```
|f(n) - g(n)| = n^{k-1} ∈ Θ(n^{k-1}) ≠ Θ(n^k)
```